# VIM Delete between X brackets

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map Ctrl-y in VIM to delete what ever it finds between brackets matching starting under cursor. It works but it erases the brackets also. This is what I'm currently using:

```
imap <c-y> <Esc><Right>d%<Insert>
```

That works fine, except as I said it removes what's under the cursor as well (i.e. matching brackets). I did find this:

```
diX
```

`X` being the bracket you are looking for; `[`, `(`, `'`, etc.

The problem with the `i` command is that I don't want to map a new key for each bracket I do this to on a regular basis, I like `%` in that it matches what ever is under cursor be it a letter `s` even.

Any way to get this to preserve brackets?

**EDIT:** Sorry, an example. I have the following text examples, (* stands for cursor):

```
(*text to be erased between brackets)
"*text to be erased between brackets"
'*text to be erased between brackets'
[*text to be erased between brackets]
{*text to be erased between brackets}
```

Basically in each of those examples I want my cursor to be on top of the bracket in question, then when I hit `Ctrl-y` it moves from Insert mode to Normal mode, removes **ALL** text or whatever is between the bracket under the cursor (under at that point since I moved to normal mode then `<Right>`) to the next one of that same bracket.

So all of those above would turn into:

```
()
""
''
[]
{}
```

Without removing the surrounding brackets. With `d%` the brackets are removed.

Comment: This isn't technically an answer to your question, so I'm just posting it as a comment, but what you want is the [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin.  It does everything you need and more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `%` only matches the other half of a pair and alphabetical charaters like `s` don't come in pairs: You'll only be able to work with `(){}[]''""<>`.

Also, editing is done in *normal* mode, not *insert* mode.

In normal mode, one possible sequence would be `v%holc`:

```
" []: normal mode cursor, |: insert mode cursor

[(]foo bar baz)
[(foo bar baz)]
[(foo bar baz])
([foo bar baz])
(|)
```

So the following mapping should satisfy your needs:

```
nnoremap <C-y> v%holc
```

Extending this mapping to make it work with *any* character would be less trivial.

I should add that `ci(` and friends are not as taxing as you think they are.

***edit***

The following function (and associated normal mode mapping) is not very smart but does exactly what you ask; feel free to modify it as you want. It works like this:

- if you hit `<C-y>` over a `({[<`, the text between the current character and its brother (`>]})`) is deleted and you are put in insert mode.
- if you hit `<C-y>` over any other character, the text between the current character and its next occurrence on the line is deleted and you are put in insert mode.

The function:

```
function! InPair()

  let l:this_char = getline('.')[col('.')-1]

  if this_char == '{' || this_char == '(' || this_char == '[' || this_char == '<'
    execute "normal! di" . this_char
  else
    execute "normal! ldt" . this_char
  endif

  startinsert

endfunction
```

The mapping:

```
nnoremap <C-y> :call InPair()<CR>
```

It is by no means perfect but it should provide a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted it to work in insert mode, hence my mapping above, the whole idea is to save me some key strokes, thanks for the suggestion though. Now, it works but only for brackets, it won't work on `'` or `"`. When I use it on those two it removes to the next bracket not quote. I've tested this by manually typing the keys in question when over the quote in normal mode `v%holc` but still it goes to the bracket not quote character. Any ideas?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, I would need a function :) thanks, I'll try it out now.

Answer (score 1):

See **:help visual-operators**.  Namely, **v_iB** to select all text between brackets {}.  So **viBd** will delete all text between 2 {}.

Answer (score 0):

let's make examples, I didn't get you very clearly... :(

you have this (* is cursor), your current mapping will change:

```
(foo*bar)

into         

*ar)
```

but you want it to be:

```
(*ar) (back to INSERT mode)
```

then you could do:

```
imap <c-y> <Esc>lv%ls
```

it will first visual select to the opening bracket, and then move right, so that the bracket won't be deleted later, then `s` will remove the visual selection and back to INSERT mode.

**OH**, I read your question again, it seems that you want to have:

```
*bar) ( INSERT mode)
```

then it is easier: (still based on your current mapping)

```
 imap <c-y> <Esc>c%
```

btw, if you want to have `(*bar) (INSERT mode)`: (you really should make an example in your question.... ^_^ )

```
imap <c-y> <Esc>v%lc
```